# Can a corp have more than 1 'Chairman Hiro' rezzed at the same time?

Tags: android-netrunner

[Chairmain Hiro](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=Chairman%20Hiro): Can a corp have more than 1 'Chairman Hiro' rezzed at the same time?

Comment: I don't think the question is self explanatory. It's self defining. It doesn't explain what you're asking. I don't play netrunner, but when I look at this card, I don't see anything about it that would indicate why it would be limited to a singleton. Can you explain why you have reservations about whether or not you can have multiples, and perhaps the situation that prompted the question?

Comment: @corsiKa, actually Chairman Hiro is a unique asset, so only one can be rezzed (or activated) at a given time.  See my answer for more details.  Also, you should learn Netrunner - it is a fantastic game :)

Comment: I agree with Twitch_City, Android: Netrunner is a fantastic game, more people should learn and play!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Chairman Hiro](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=Chairman%20Hiro) is a unique asset (there is a diamond next to the card name designating this status).  While multiple unique cards may be installed simultaneously, only one may be rezzed at a time.

So, if you have two Chairman Hiro's installed, and one is rezzed and the runner runs on it, you could conceivably rez the second Hiro which would cause the first one to trash itself before the runner accesses it (so long as you do this during a legal paid ability window).

Comment: Ah the diamond. That's the key - that's the information that will help future visitors! :)

Comment: Thank you so much Twitch_City; for some reason I am not able to upvote your answer, but I appreciate it a lot. Thank you! =)

Comment: Maybe you could add the relevant section of the rule book to your answer to improve your answer further. Nice to see A:NR gets some love here on this site :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the Android Netrunner rulebook:

> Unique Cards
>
> Some cards have a unique symbol (◆) in front of their title. There can be only one unique card of the same title active at a time. If a card with a unique title becomes active, any other card that shares its title is immediately trashed. This trashing cannot be prevented.

Chairman Hiro has the diamond in front of his name, marking him as unique. You can have multiple copies installed at a given time, but you can't have more than one of those copies rezzed.